# Something is regenerate ports.conf

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, mod-ssl, raspbian

Since the last update of my Raspbian "something" is updating my apache ports.conf file by adding these two lines automatically:

```
Listen 81
```

And:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

But I need you to listen to the port 4443 because I'm using sslh to listen 443

This is the full ports.conf file

```
Listen 80
#Listen 10008
Listen 81

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 192.168.21.106:4443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 192.168.21.106:4443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Does anyone know what is making this changes?

Comment: What is running on the Pi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of searching, in my case the cron job task of `certbot` was modifying the file `ports.conf`.

I disable this job, and renew my certs with `certbot -i apache --webroot` and entering the path when request it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using some sort of admin panel such as Webmin or cPanel,  or a configuration management tool such as Puppet, Ansible or Salt there should be no changes applied to your server configurations from any other source than Debians package manager (`dpkg(1)`).

This might happen if you've ran distribution upgrades, or have unattended upgrades enabled in your server. This is generally logged in `/var/log/dpkg.log`.

You can override this behavior to make sure there is no configuration changes applied to any of your packages by adding following lines to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/local.conf`:

`Dpkg::Options {
   "--force-confdef";
   "--force-confold";
}`

To give you an overview of these options:

**--force-confdef**: *ask dpkg to decide alone when it can and prompt otherwise. This is the default behavior of dpkg and this option is mainly useful in combination with --force-confold.*

**--force-confold**: *do not modify the current configuration file, the new version is installed with a .dpkg-dist suffix. With this option alone, even configuration files that you have not modified are left untouched. You need to combine it with --force-confdef to let dpkg overwrite configuration files that you have not modified.*

You can also achieve this with `ucf(1)` by adding your configuration to `/etc/ucf.conf.` To be able to detect changes to the file you can use `inotify` in conjuction with some other commands like `lsof`. Let me know if you want further help with that.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, I don't use any admin panel. Yes I run an a distribution upgrade, and may be dpkg upgrade some configuration in the system. I will try with inotify to locate who is modifying the file, and from there I will make the corrections. Thanks for your help

Comment: That may explain why your configuration is overriden. You can display your current dpkg config with `apt-config dump`. Please accept this as an answer, if this was of any help. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that the file is modified automatically without having made any upgrade with `apt`. Normally it is at night, when I wake up apache is down because something has changed ports.conf that file and restart apache. (And apache don't start because the port 443 is in use by `sslh`)

Comment: If you want a quick workaround before you manage to track down which file is causing the problems, you could always add an immutable attribute to ports.conf, with `chattr +i ports.conf`. Apart from inotify, you can use `auditd` or sysdig `falco` to monitor filesystem changes. It should be more reliable as it hooks directly into the syscall.

Comment: Thanks for your help William, I FOUND IT! It's the cron job of `certbot` when it try to renew the certificates, overwrite ports.conf adding the SSL port. Now I'm looking for how to disable that